# Canvas doesn't draw over specific point

Tags: java, javafx

### Canvas Java Fx

**I want to draw on a Pane and implemented a zoom function, but when I zoom in the program draws out of the pane.**

I'm wondering because I set the pane to `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth`, to understand my Problem I made a picture of the program. 
I searched already in the web, but didn't find anything about javafx close to this problem.

I scale with

```
     this.pane.setScaleX(2);
    this.pane.setScaleY(2);
```

I dont have much expirience with javafx and dont know if there is a function to limit the width and height range of panes?

[Problem rightside on zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFxMO.png)

Comment: There's no way to answer this without you showing some implementation (preferably one of these http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), what you tried, what you expected to happen, what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle documentation for Pane says:

"Pane does not clip its content by default, so it is possible that childrens' bounds may extend outside its own bounds, either if children are positioned at negative coordinates or the pane is resized smaller than its preferred size."

You may try something like this:

```
package jfxlib.scene.layout;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class ClipPane extends Pane {
    public ClipPane() {
        Rectangle clipRect = new Rectangle();
        setClip(clipRect);
        layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            clipRect.setWidth(newValue.getWidth());
            clipRect.setHeight(newValue.getHeight());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Arent there any other pane types where it isnt possible children bounds extend outside its own bounds?
`this.drawpane.getChildren().add(new Line(300, 0, 300, 240));
        this.drawpane.getChildren().add(new Line(-10, 125, 650, 125));`
this is the cross I add but when i scale the cross should not scale I thought about a solution that I put the cross in his own Pane

Comment: The answer to your second question is put your cross into a Group and when you scale the content of your pane by a factor of 2 for example then you have to scale the cross group by a factor of 1/2 so it stays the same size.